# How to find a word in multiple files

Tags: find

Regards for all of you. I have a question about Borland Builder code.

I have Table1 with DataSource conected on paradox.DB (inside that base are topics of my eBox saved in some folder).

Now I am using EditBox and Button to execute filter in DBGrid and I wanna make search to find a word (from EditBox) in multiple filles whereever is thtat word mentioned in my eBox colection.

All my eBox are in pdf format.

Is it possible??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve